# Using 'move' command instead of 'xcopy' in a loop

Tags: batch-file, xcopy, rmdir

This line of code fines all folders in a directory that have a certain bit of text in common and copies all the contents of those folders to a new destination.

```
dir /b /s /a:d "\\SERVER\Path\Directory\*FolderTag" | for /f "delims=\; tokens=3,4,5*" %%a in ('findstr FolderTag') do @xcopy /i /s /y "\\SERVER\Path\Directory\%%b\%%c" "E:\%%b\"
```

It works like a charm. But I'd like to be able to move the files instead of just copying them so that they are removed from their original location. I can't simply replace `xcopy` with `move` but I can't figure out how to convert the structure of this loop into one that will work with move. Would it be easier just to write another loop that deletes the files? I doubt `rm` instead of `xcopy` would work and I'm always a little scared to touch `rm`.

I tried putting together a working example batch script but because the loop is so dependent on the path structure, i wasn't able to get it working. So basically my question revolves around my implementation of `xcopy` in this loop and how it could be changed to let `move` work in its place.

Comment: `move` does not exactly behave the same way when it comes to directories, so it might be more reliable to keep `xcopy` and just to append `&& rm /S /Q "\\SERVER\Path\Directory\%%b\%%c"`...

Comment: @aschipfl So would that be added directly after the rest of the loop?

`dir /b /s /a:d "\\SERVER\Path\Directory\*FolderTag" | for /f "delims=\; tokens=3,4,5*" 
%%a in ('findstr FolderTag') do @xcopy /i /s /y "\\SERVER\Path\Directory\%%b\%%c" "E:\%%b\" && rm /S /Q "\\SERVER\Path\Directory\%%b\%%c\%%d"`?

I ask because I'm getting some errors with that.

Comment: Also `rm` isn't a windows command. Its `del`.

Comment: Sorry, actually I meant [`rd` = `rmdir`](http://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) rather than `rm`... the command [`del` = `erase`](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) deletes files only but no directories...

Comment: @aschipfl but I only want to delete the files inside the directory and not the directory itself.

Comment: You were talking about using `move` instead of `xcopy /S`, so I was assuming you want to move the entire source directory tree with all its contents (both files and directories); if you do not want that, you need to be more specific in your question (please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40939986/edit) accordingly)...

Answer (score 2):

Move should work, but you need to create the folder you're moving to first

Also, you can have multiple commands executing on each iteration of a for loop by using brackets

So the following should work

```
dir /b /s /a:d "\\SERVER\Path\Directory\*FolderTag" | for /f "delims=\; tokens=3,4,5*" 
%%a in ('findstr FolderTag') do (
mkdir "E:\%%b"
@move /Y "\\SERVER\Path\Directory\%%b\%%c" "E:\%%b\"
)
```